# Not calculating volume properly

Tags: c#

```
volume = (4/3 * PI) * (Math.Pow(5, 3));
return volume;
```

The code above should return 523.6 but it returns 392.7.  I can't figure it out but its probably something stupid that I am missing. 
Changing it to be a double literal does not change the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4 and 3 are both ints so dividing them will produce an int, 1. This is probably not the value you were expecting.

You have to cast the 4 to a double before computing the quotient with 3.

Comment: cast or make at least one of them a double literal, e.g. `4.0`

Answer (score 1):

You can also just change 4 to 4.0, since yes the issue is that it is a integer so something called [Integer Division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) happens.

```
volume = (4.0/3.0 * PI) * (Math.Pow(5, 3));
return volume;
```

Answer (score -5):

cast to double

```
double volume = (4.0 / 3.0 * Math.PI) * (Math.Pow(5, 3));
```

Comment: This experiences the same problem because it calculates `4 / 3` using integer division. https://www.ideone.com/nyu3Xt